# Regex to use in JavaScript string with not more than n number of digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a username in jquery using a regex, with following rules

- String must start with a letter
- String can have 0(m) to 4(n) digits anywhere or no more than 4(n)
- Size of the string must be between 6(p) and 20(q)

**Following should fail**

- `1djgWWq` (starts with a digit)
- `wwwhg` (length less than 6)
- `ky12yu781` (more than 4 digits)

**Following should pass**

- `tableten`
- `table10`
- `tab7le10`

I tried following regex which is good, except its not match 4 digits anywhere in the string

```
^(?=^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,20}$)(?=^(?:(?!\d{4}).)*$).*$
```

[Sample regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eB8fF9/1)

Note: m,n, p,q integer variable

> EDIT 1

Sebastian Proske> Yes letters numbers and _ -
I want to try validate fields in a form using different regex for each field, so regex per one filed, I want to stick to one regex for cleaner code.
bellow is sample untested code to give you a idea what I'm trying to do.
Sebastian Proske answer is the best one for my work. Thanks everyone.

```
Sample 1<input id="ds1" type="text" class="validate" data-validate='{"regex":"^[a-z0-9]{4,7}$"}' /><br/>
Sample 2...
Sample 3...
Active Sample <input id="as" type="text" class="validate" data-validate='{"regex":"^(?=^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,20}$)(?=^(?:(?!\d{4}).)*$).*$"}' /><br/>
<input id="f1SubmitBtn" type="button" value="Test" onclick="f1Submit();" /><br/>
<script>
  function f1Submit() {
  $('.validate').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('validate').regex.test(this.value)) {
      console.log(this.value + " No!");
    }
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use multiple statements to do what you're doing to check and what not? Or must everything fit into one regex?

Comment: If you use one statement to check for more than for digits such as var regex = /\d+/g; and then do this regex.exec(string). This will return an array with all digits and you can check for the length.

Comment: https://simple-regex.com/

Comment: I want to try validate fields in a form using different regex for the field, so per one filed, I want to stick to one regex for cleaner code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your original regex I assume that `_` and `-` are also allowed characters. You can test your names with the regex `/^(?!(?:\D*\d){5})[a-z][\w-]{5,19}$/i`.

A little breakdown:

- `^` is an anchor for the start of the string
- `(?!(?:\D*\d){5})` is a negative lookahead checking for the presence of 5 digits (which will cause the match to fail)
- `[a-z]` the first character has to be a letter
- `[\w-]{5,19}` length between 6 and 20, word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and minus are allowed
- `$` is an anchor for the end of the string
- `i` is the case-insensitivity modifier

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iN1uX2/1)

Comment: This works for all the tests I could think to throw at it

Answer (score 1):

I could accomplish this (I hope) with two regexes, and doing `and` between the results,

The first one is

```
^[a-zA-A][a-zA-Z0-9]{5,19}$
```

which makes the string start with a letter and limits the length to 6-20

and the second one is

```
^[^\d]*?(\d|\d[^\d]+){0,4}$
```

which limits the number of digits to 0-4

I believe you want regex for speed, and I think doing logical `and` between 2 regex results can also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some logic to achieve the behaviour you want:

```
<script>

    function matches(str, m, n, p, q) {

        var numDigits = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').length;

        if(m <= numDigits && numDigits <= n) {
            return new RegExp('^[A-Za-z].{' + (p - 1) + ',' + (q - 1) + '}$').test(str);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    var tests = ['1djgWWq', 'wwwhg', 'ky12yu781', 'tableten', 'table10','tableten'];

    for(var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
        console.log(tests[i] + ' -> ' + matches(tests[i], 0, 4, 6, 20));
    }

</script>
```

The results are:

```
1djgWWq -> false
wwwhg -> false
ky12yu781 -> false
tableten -> true
table10 -> true
tableten -> true
```

Here the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z7a6fgfg/